# CountVectorizer() not working with single letter word

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

Consider I have to apply CountVectorizer() on the following data:

```
words = [
     'A am is',
     'This the a',
     'the am is',
     'this a am',
]
```

I did the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(X.toarray())
```

It returns the following:

```
[[1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1]]
```

For reference `print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())` prints `['am', 'is', 'the', 'this']`

Why is 'a' not being read??
Is it that single letter words don't count as words in CountVectorizer()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

> **token_pattern**
>
> Regular expression denoting what constitutes a
> “token”, only used if analyzer == 'word'. The default regexp select
> tokens of 2 or more alphanumeric characters (punctuation is completely
> ignored and always treated as a token separator).

All the single character tokens are ignored by the default tokenizer. That is the reason why `a` is missing.

If you want single character tokens to be in the vocabulary, then you have to use a costume tokenizer.

#### Sample Code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda txt: txt.split())
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(words)
print (vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Output:

```
['a', 'am', 'is', 'the', 'this']
```

Comment: how does  "tokenizer=lambda txt: txt.split()" work? what is happening here?

Comment: `lambda txt: txt.split()` is a function that takes the text and splits it at space each of which is now a token used by the `CountVectorizer`